# How to create cross-tab with multiple sum at ireport

Tags: ireport

im trying to create table with multiple sum using cross-tab in ireport, but i think cross-tab don't support multiple sum. my query is look like

```
|no|info     |city     |M    |F    |Total    |
|1 |info1    |bandung  |10   |5    |15       | 
|2 |info1    |jakarta  |13   |7    |20       |
```

and im looking for something like

```
|no|info     |bandung |jakarta |total   |
|__|_________|M |F |T |M |F |T |M |F |T |
|1 |info1    |10|5 |15|13|7 |20|23|12|35|
```

thanks before, sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved my problem, just drag item from pallet panel to add another variable.